# ImageResizer best settings for max quality

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using [image resizer](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4) for resizing photos in jpg format. Photos mostly contains people, but I've some problem with quality, even I set quality=100 It's not satisfying. Resized photo Is blurred and looks ugly :). I'm using mode=pad, scale=canvas, trimming and size properties. Which plugins, parameters and setting is best for get max quality resized photos?

Comment: What's the size of your image (old and new)?

Comment: New 250x350, old are diffrent, but almost all have high resolution like 2000x3000

Comment: Do you have a high-dpi display? You may want to add &zoom=2 and embed the URLs in a srcset attribute in order to ensure that the browser isn't upscaling the image.

Comment: I think it does not depend on the display, it appears on many devices, even if I download a photo to disk and open it is of poor quality

Comment: Opening the photo on disk will still display it without dpi scaling.

Answer (score 0):

You may be expecting more sharpening to be applied during resizing. If you use Imageflow.NET, or the ImageResizer FastScaling plugin, you can apply this using `f.sharpen=15&down.filter=mitchell`.